# ¿Cómo subir un HTML al servidor con NODE js y express?

Tags: javascript, html5, nodejs, express, servidor

tal vez mi pregunta no se explique de la mejor manera. El dilema es que sí se sube el HTML en el servidor local, pero, mi hoja de estilos y mi archivo de javascript están aparte, pero en la misma carpeta, asi como las imagenes que ocupo. Ya puse los estilos en un tag  y lo de javascript en , se que no es lo mejor, pero funciona. Ahora el problema es con las imagenes. Aqui esta el código :

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get("/", index);

function index(peticion, respuesta) {

    respuesta.sendfile("campo.html");
}

app.listen(8080);
```

Creo que es por el "sendfile()".

PD: Estoy empezando :o

Answer (score 1):

Porqué no en lugar de enviar un archivo creas una ruta estática y todos tus contenidos fijos los sirves con esta ruta? algo así como

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
router.use('/contenido',express.static('/mi_carpeta_en_servidor'));
app.use('/',router);
app.listen(8080);
```

Así cuando entres a http://servidor/contenido tendrás servida la carpeta mi_carpeta_en_servidor intacta.

No tengo un entorno de pruebas para probar el código, pero la idea principal está en la linea 4.

Además así puedes introducir tu lógica de negocio en otras rutas, como

```
router.get('/sumar',(peticion,respuesta)=>{
  respuesta.json({
    suma: parseFloat(peticion.body.a) + parseFloat(peticion.body.b)
  });
});
```

o cosas por el estilo

Comment: Ohhh ya, muchas gracias Al, lo voy a checar